# Download the place's website and priceLevel (Google places, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, google-places-api

I created this class

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

private let geometryKey = "geometry"
private let locationKey = "location"
private let latitudeKey = "lat"
private let longitudeKey = "lng"
private let nameKey = "name"
private let openingHoursKey = "opening_hours"
private let openNowKey = "open_now"
private let vicinityKey = "vicinity"
private let typesKey = "types"
private let photosKey = "photos"
private let phoneNumberKey = "phoneNumber"
private let ratingKey = "rating"
private let priceLevelKey = "priceLevel"
private let websiteKey = "website"


class QPlace: NSObject  {

    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
    var name: String?
    var photos: [QPhoto]?
    var vicinity: String?
    var isOpen: Bool?
    var types: [String]?
    var rating: Float?
    var priceLevel: Int?
    var website: String?

    init(placeInfo:[String: Any]) {
        // coordinates
        if let g = placeInfo[geometryKey] as? [String:Any] {
            if let l = g[locationKey] as? [String:Double] {
                if let lat = l[latitudeKey], let lng = l[longitudeKey] {
                    location = CLLocationCoordinate2D.init(latitude: lat, longitude: lng)
                }
            }
        }





        // name
        name = placeInfo[nameKey] as? String

        // opening hours
        if let oh = placeInfo[openingHoursKey] as? [String:Any] {
            if let on = oh[openNowKey] as? Bool {
                isOpen = on
            }
        }

        // vicinity
        vicinity = placeInfo[vicinityKey] as? String

        // types
        types = placeInfo[typesKey] as? [String]

        // rating
        rating = placeInfo[ratingKey] as? Float

        //priceLevel
        priceLevel = placeInfo[priceLevelKey] as? Int

        website = placeInfo[websiteKey] as? String

        // photos
        photos = [QPhoto]()
        if let ps = placeInfo[photosKey] as? [[String:Any]] {
            for p in ps {
                photos?.append(QPhoto.init(photoInfo: p))
            }
        }
    }

    func getDescription() -> String {

        var s : [String] = []

        if let types = types {
            s.append("\(types.joined(separator: ", "))")
        }

        if let rating = rating {
            s.append("Rating: \(rating)")
        }

        if let priceLevel = priceLevel {
            s.append("PriceLevel: \(priceLevel)")
        }

        if let website = website {
            s.append("\(website)")
        }

         if let isOpen = isOpen {
            s.append(isOpen ? "OPEN NOW" : "CLOSED NOW")
        }

        if let vicinity = vicinity {
            s.append("\(vicinity)")
        }
        return s.joined(separator: "\n")
    }


 func heightForComment(_ font: UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let desc = getDescription()
        let rect = NSString(string: desc).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)
        return ceil(rect.height)
    }


}
```

to get the place's details that i'll show in a VC of my application by calling this function   `func getDescription() -> String { }` but my problem and i don't know why (because i follow the documentation of google places API) is that the website and also the price level not working, so when in the viewController i call the function `getDescription()` it load all place's details which i added in that function, but not the website and the price level. What i did wrong? How can i adjust it?

UPDATE

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/place-details

```
static func getNearbyPlaces(by category:String, coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D, radius:Int, token: String?, completion: @escaping (QNearbyPlacesResponse?, Error?) -> Void) {

        var params : [String : Any]

        if let t = token {
            params = [
                "key" : AppDelegate.googlePlacesAPIKey,
                "pagetoken" : t,
            ]
        } else {
            params = [
                "key" : AppDelegate.googlePlacesAPIKey,      
                "radius" : radius,
                "location" : "\(coordinates.latitude),\(coordinates.longitude)",
                "type" : category.lowercased()
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service):

The key for price level is `price_level` but you have used `priceLevel` which might be why you are not seeing the prices

As for website I think it could be case that there is no data available for the property you have selected.

Comment: but you think i added the website correctly in my class, the format is this website = placeInfo[websiteKey] as? String           ?

Comment: if you are seeing other values then the way website is implemented, seem to be correct. Why don't you try and print the raw json before parsing to see if you are getting website value from Google API

Comment: i tried to use price_level and searched a lot of places but same result, not load

Comment: can you print `placeInfo` received by the method before parsing and see if the values are shown in the debugger

Comment: ok i tried, but the values of website and price_level are not shown in the debugger

Comment: if you look here https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/place-details , show that there is data for website

Comment: yes, but it is not guaranteed to give values if google doesn't have data for this.

Comment: i tried with a lot of places, is strange that no-one has levelprice or website, anyway looking in the docs i found - (NSURL*) website [read, copy]
 for website and - (GMSPlacesPriceLevel) priceLevel [read, assign] for price level, maybe my format is wrong? how can i change what i have with this (NSURL and placespricelevel)

Comment: if you are using the SDK from google then this is done automatically for you. If you are using HTTP endpoint then json provides URLs as string so what you are doing is correct.

Comment: carbonr have a look to the new update, possibile the cause is that part of code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159103/discussion-between-carbonr-and-tvenden).